# Eclipse-CDT: How do I configure the debugger to stop on an exception?

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, gdb, eclipse-cdt

This might be a GDB question.. but I'd like to run my app in the debugger and have the debugger break when an exception is thrown, so I can see where the code is and what its doing at that time.

I do this often in Visual Studio using the Debug -> Exceptions dialog, checking the 'Thrown' column beside the type of exceptions I'd like to stop on.

- Alex

Answer (score 39):

You can get the equivalent of gdb catchpoints in eclipse by:

From breakpoints view, invoke action(small triangle pointing downwards near the maximize button) -> Add Event Breakpoint (C/C++) -> Exception Thrown.

Answer (score 3):

The best I found is [news.eclipse.tools.cdt: Re: Catching C++ exceptions at point of throw](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/36202/#msg_117573):

> Meanwhile, you can go at the GDB
>   console in eclipse and type "catch
>   throw", like you are did with gdb, 
>   'til we find away to integrate this
>   feature in CDT.

Comment: I went through the tutorial, I don't see anything about breaking on exceptions, did I miss it?

Comment: Link seems broken ("Page cannot be crawled or displayed due to robots.txt.")

Comment: @Gabriel Schreiber Thanks. I fixed the link.