# Finding where std::out_of_range is thrown by std::vector.at()

Tags: c++, exception, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Normally I would leave it unhandled and the debugger (gdb, Eclipse CDT) would show me the call stack. Unfortunately the code is being called by a third party library which absorbs all exceptions. I can catch the exception before the third party library however I cannot see the call stack (stack-unwinding?).

How can I figure out where the exception was thrown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would [catchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html) help? You can break whenever an exception is thrown by entering the `catch throw` command in gdb. In Eclipse, you can do this through the gdb console. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1109922/341970).

Comment: Upvote and thanks! Yes, in this particular case they helped :) But for the future: can I filter according to the type of exception? The third party library uses exceptions to flow control... so I would get too many notifications about exceptions being thrown.

Comment: @Ali: Sorry, what I know is in the link. I don't have any actual experience with this. I don't see a way to specify the exception type.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer but please add more info for the general audience what to do (type catch throw in the gdb console) and this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1109922/341970

Answer (score 4):

You can put a breakpoint in the constructor for the exception object. Since this occurs before the exception is thrown, you get great visibility into the calling code.

Comment: Upvoted and thanks! I cannot filter exceptions with the gdb catch throw solution, however, putting a breakpoint where out_of_range is thrown pretty much solves the problem.